# MVC CheckBoxFor IE 11/Chrome Issue

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have come across an issue that I have having trouble getting past.  I have a view that is using the the following checkbox in a preview popup window:

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.Payee)
```

In IE 10, this checkbox passes the value back to the code and works correctly.  However, in IE 11 and Chrome this value is not being passed back.  Has anyone encountered this before or have suggestions of an approach to resolve this issue?

**Update:**

In looking a little more I did notice the query strings between IE 10 (works) and Chrome(does not work) are different.

In IE 10 query string has:

```
Payee=true&Payee=false
```

In Chrome the query string has:

```
Payee%5b%5d=true&Payee%5b%5d=false
```

Is there a way to get it to pass the above query string?  Or am I going in the wrong direction?

Thanks!

Comment: Compatibility mode in IE?

Comment: I run the site on a machine with IE 11 doing the IE 10 emulation and it works just fine, but I cannot use that as the solution sadly.  :)

Comment: I found the solution to the issue.  I needed to add the following to get it to pass the traditional query string.

    $.ajaxSettings.traditional = true;

Comment: It would be great if you take the solution you found and post a full answer (use the "post answer" button below).

Comment: Thanks for showing me where the button is to answer it...I have to wait 8 hours before I can submit the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution to the issue. Needed to add the following code to the view and it runs great now!  I am now looking into why IE 11 and Chrome try to pass along %5b%5d (brackets) along with the query string where as IE 10 does not.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
           $.ajaxSettings.traditional = true;
        })
    </script>
```